# Until the rain season ended... (Use of future tense)

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, future-tense

> After all the mud that she had to clean up from the passenger seat's feet
>   space, Anne swore that nobody would enter her car again until the rain
>   season **ended**.

At a first reading I find this sentence sounding grammatically correct, but after reading it again I wonder if it's okay using that past tense to express an action in progress that is expected to conclude in the future.

If there are any, feel free to correct my other mistakes. It improves my understanding of the native speakers' fluency. Best!

P.S.: The sentence is self-genius, no source. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After all the mud that she had to clean up from the passenger <strike>seat</strike>'s
>   **foot** space, Anne swore that nobody would enter her car again until the **rainy** season ended.

Comment: I would be inclined to say "had ended", but "ended" is fine as well.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I was afraid of not being to vague, regarding the superfluous use of "seat", I considered mentioning it because no passenger in particular made the trouble. However, your correction sounds better. About the pluralization of the adjective, and using the noun form of "rain" I have no excuse, I should be ashamed of myself. Thanks! :)

Comment: We all make mistakes - the only shame would be not admitting them! If this is the best anwser, please check the "accept" box.

Comment: @Colin Fine, indeed, using simple past makes one think that during the time the rainy season reached an ending, people would be able to get a ride in her car again. Using the perfect form makes her look rather exigent, as if not until the last drop someone could set their foot inside her vehicle.